# Is it possible to have a generic WCF service for handling multiple MSMQ endpoints?

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq, msmqintegrationbinding

Our team is building a service for processing messages from multiple remote MSMQ queues using WCF (via [msmqIntegrationBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731792(v=vs.110).aspx)). We would like to have the ability to throttle different groups of queues (via [serviceThrottling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731379(v=vs.110).aspx)) based on the amount of resources they typically consume.

My idea is to have a single service type processing messages from multiple queues and determining what to do with them based on the type of message. Unfortunately, I can't figure out a generic way to use [`MsmqMessage<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms600458(v=vs.110).aspx) as it's expecting the exact type of the message. `MsmqMessage<object>` doesn't work because I think it's trying to find a serializer for type `object`.

Any ideas on how to get this work or alternative approaches? Preferably still using WCF since it has dead-letter handling already built-in.

Example Configuration:

```
<services>
    <service name="MessageProcessor.LowResourceMsmqReceiverService" behaviorConfiguration="LowResourceMsmqServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="msmq.formatname:DIRECT=OS:.\private$\EmailQueue" binding="msmqIntegrationBinding" bindingConfiguration="IncomingMessageBinding" contract="MessageProcessor.IMsmqReceiverService" />
        <endpoint address="msmq.formatname:DIRECT=OS:.\private$\LoggingQueue" binding="msmqIntegrationBinding" bindingConfiguration="IncomingMessageBinding" contract="MessageProcessor.IMsmqReceiverService" />
    </service>
    <service name="MessageProcessor.HighResourceMsmqReceiverService" behaviorConfiguration="HighResourceMsmqServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="msmq.formatname:DIRECT=OS:.\private$\DataImportQueue" binding="msmqIntegrationBinding" bindingConfiguration="IncomingMessageBinding" contract="MessageProcessor.IMsmqReceiverService" />
        <endpoint address="msmq.formatname:DIRECT=OS:.\private$\DataExportQueue" binding="msmqIntegrationBinding" bindingConfiguration="IncomingMessageBinding" contract="MessageProcessor.IMsmqReceiverService" />
    </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="LowResourceMsmqServiceBehavior">
            <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="50" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="HighResourceMsmqServiceBehavior">
            <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="3" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Example Contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(object))]
public interface IMsmqReceiverService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
    void Receive(MsmqMessage<object> message);
}

[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public abstract class TransactionalMsmqReceiverService : IMsmqReceiverService
{
    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
    [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
    public void Receive(MsmqMessage<object> message)
    {
        // TODO: Handle multiple message types here
    }
}

public sealed class LowResourceMsmqReceiverService : TransactionalMsmqReceiverService { }

public sealed class HighResourceMsmqReceiverService : TransactionalMsmqReceiverService { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not actually caused by `MsmqMessage<object>`.

When the queued messages are in XML format, the service uses the `ServiceKnownTypeAttribute` to determine what types are supported by the service for XML (de)serialization. In this case, `object` isn't really a valid serializable type so it was probably ignored.

In order to support generic processing of XML messages, you can add `[ServiceKnownType(typeof(XElement))]` to your service contract and accept `MsmqMessage<object>` as the argument to your service method. This will allow you to check properties of the `MsmqMessage<T>` object to determine how it should be processed. Another possible option would be to use the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms575141(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `ServiceKnownTypeAttribute` that accepts a method parameter to dynamically build a list of your supported types.

The only other [serialization format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.msmqintegration.msmqmessageserializationformat.aspx) I checked is `Binary`, so keep in mind they are all likely processed differently. For the `Binary` format specifically, no `ServiceKnownTypeAttribute` is required as the type information is included in the binary payload (only tested this with `System.Guid`). If you intend to use the `Binary` format, it's important you continue to use `MsmqMessage<object>` rather than `MsmqMessage<XElement>` as the actual object type will come through instead of `XElement`.